# VichUploaderBundle, Form\Type\VichImageType Error Produccion

Tags: php, symfony, vichuploaderbundle

First of all, I apologize for my basic use of english, I hope you can understand me.
I'm doing a deployment of a project, the development was on **Symfony 5.1**, using **easyadmin-bundle 3.1**, and **vich/uploader-bundle 1.15**. On my localhost that works great, but when I move to production, on my dashboard, can't **'Create New'** or **'Edit'** in any entity who has images inside, it throw me this error.

> An error has occurred resolving the options of the form "Vich\UploaderBundle\Form\Type\VichImageType": The options "upload_dir", "upload_filename" do not exist.

https://i.ibb.co/gWRjPLm/Screenshot-2020-11-20-An-error-has-occurred-resolving-the-options-of-the-form-Vich-Uploader-Bundle-F.png

The only place I find **upload_dir**, is inside vendor folder.

https://i.ibb.co/VHw39z5/Screenshot-2020-11-20-Symfony-Profiler.png

My entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ColoresRepository::class)
 * @Vich\Uploadable()
 */
class Colores
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=30)
     */
    private $nombre;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $thumbnail;

    /**
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="colores", fileNameProperty="thumbnail")
     */
    private $thumbnailFile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime();
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getThumbnailFile()
    {
        return $this->thumbnailFile;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $thumbnailFile
     */
    public function setThumbnailFile($thumbnailFile): void
    {
        $this->thumbnailFile = $thumbnailFile;

        if($thumbnailFile) {
            $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getThumbnail()
    {
        return $this->thumbnail;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $thumbnail
     */
    public function setThumbnail($thumbnail): void
    {
        $this->thumbnail = $thumbnail;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $updatedAt): self
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNombre(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nombre;
    }

    public function setNombre(string $nombre): self
    {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->nombre;
    }

}
```

My Dashboard

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Dashboard;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\MenuItem;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Router\CrudUrlGenerator;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractDashboardController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use App\Entity\Colores;




class DashboardController extends AbstractDashboardController
{
    /**
     * @Route("admin", name="admin")
     */
    public function index(): Response
    {
        $routeBuilder = $this->get(CrudUrlGenerator::class)->build();

        return $this->redirect($routeBuilder->setController(ColoresCrudController::class)->generateUrl());
    }

    public function configureDashboard(): Dashboard
    {
        return Dashboard::new()
            ->setTitle('Test Site');
    }

    public function configureMenuItems(): iterable
    {
        yield MenuItem::section('DESTACADOS');
        yield MenuItem::linkToCrud('Colores', 'fa fa-paint-brush', Colores::class);

}
```

My Crud controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use App\Entity\Colores;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractCrudController;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\ImageField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\TextField;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Form\Type\VichImageType;

class ColoresCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
    {
        return Colores::class;
    }

    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        return [
            TextField::new('nombre'),
            ImageField::new('thumbnailFile')
                ->setFormType(VichImageType::class)->onlyOnForms(),
            ImageField::new('thumbnail')
                ->setBasePath('/images/colores')->hideOnForm()
        ];
    }

}
```

vich_uploader.yaml

```
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm

    mappings:
        colores:
            uri_prefix: /images/colores
            upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/images/colores'
            namer: Vich\UploaderBundle\Naming\UniqidNamer
```

Comment: Your English is fine.
As to your question: it seems that the `upload_dir` and `upload_filename` options are missing from your application's config.

Answer (score 3):

Using setFormType is an ["undocumented hack"](https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/commit/fd3dbf81562ec3130fc8b91281f0c6eb0215ed1b#commitcomment-44299016)

There is an [issue with the v3.1.8 and the ImageField](https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/issues/3966).

You can try this syntax :

```
$filename     = ImageField::new('filename', 'File')
                          ->setBasePath('uploads/contact_message')
                          ->setUploadDir('public/uploads/contact_message/');
```

If it doesn't work you can roll back to v.3.1.7 (force the version in your composer.json) and using the [old syntax](https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/issues/3456#issuecomment-654198515) with 2 field ( the file and the filename)

```
$avatar = ImageField::new('avatar')->setBasePath('uploads/images/users')->setLabel('Photo');
$avatarFile = ImageField::new('avatarFile')->setFormType(VichImageType::class);

 if (Crud::PAGE_INDEX === $pageName) {
            return [ $avatar];
     } elseif (Crud::PAGE_EDIT=== $pageName) {
return [$avatarFile];
```

Comment: Yup, I roll back to v 3.1.7, took me a while figure out that solution. Thx for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own Custom Field (see https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/fields.html#creating-custom-fields) like this :

```
namespace App\Admin\Field;

use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Contracts\Field\FieldInterface;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\FieldTrait;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Form\Type\VichImageType;

class VichImageField implements FieldInterface
{
    use FieldTrait;

    public static function new(string $propertyName, ?string $label = null): self
    {
        return (new self())
            ->setProperty($propertyName)
            ->setLabel($label)
            ->setFormType(VichImageType::class)
            ->setCustomOption('image_uri', null)
            ->setCustomOption('download_uri', null)
            ;
    }

    public function setImageUri($imageUri): self
    {
        $this->setCustomOption('image_uri', $imageUri);

        return $this;
    }

    public function setDownloadUri($downloadUri): self
    {
        $this->setCustomOption('download_uri', $downloadUri);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And the use it in your crud controller configureFileds method :

```
            VichImageField::new('avatarFile', 'Avatar')
            ->setDownloadUri('public/' . $this->getParameter('app.path.user_avatars'))
            ->setImageUri($this->getParameter('app.path.user_avatars'))
        ,
```

It works with the last EasyAdminBundle > v3.1.7